# python input() takes old stdin before input() is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, io, stdin

Python3's `input()` seems to take old std input between two calls to `input()`. Is there a way to ignore the old input, and take new input only (after `input()` gets called)?

```
import time

a = input('type something') # type "1"
print('\ngot: %s' % a)

time.sleep(5) # type "2" before timer expires

b = input('type something more')
print('\ngot: %s' % b)
```

output:

```
$ python3 input_test.py
type something
got: 1

type something more
got: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flush the input buffer prior to the second `input()`, like so

```
import time
import sys
from termios import tcflush, TCIFLUSH

a = input('type something') # type "1"
print('\ngot: %s' % a)

time.sleep(5) # type "2" before timer expires

tcflush(sys.stdin, TCIFLUSH) # flush input stream

b = input('type something more')
print('\ngot: %s' % b)
```